# VBA: Use First Formula in IF-OR Statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this formula in VBA:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(A2=""ETG_C"",A2=""ETGC""),C2,""na"")"
```

when I look at the `activecell` it actually returns this formula:

```
=IF(OR('A2'="ETG_C",'A2'="ETGC"),$B:$B,"na")
```

how do I force it to adhere to the first formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` uses the other kind of cell addresses, where you name them row 1 col 1. Use `ActiveCell.Formula`!

Answer (score 1):

the reason why it's showing $B:$B is because your VBA formula contains C2. 
Excel's VBA is interpreting this as the 2nd column in the worksheet because you are using the FormulaR1C1 method.

Put C2 in double quotes.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(A2=""ETG_C"",A2=""ETGC""),""C2"",""na"")"
```